# Windows 7 SP1 x64 Occasional Powershell Error Message- There is no disk in the drive

Tags: windows-7, powershell

Every once in a while when I launch powershell on my Windows 7 SP1 x64 machine I get this error.

[image: powershell error "There is no disk in the drive"]

None of the buttons will get rid of the error, it just comes back, I have to close the broken powershell window to dismiss the error. A reboot will fix it for a while until it decides to come back (not a real solution). Any ideas on why powershell would intermittently look for a disk?

Comment: are there any errors or warnings in your systemlog?

Comment: - System 

  - Provider 

   [ Name]  Application Popup 
 
  - EventID 26 

   [ Qualifiers]  16384 
 
   Level 4 
 
   Task 0 
 
   Keywords 0x80000000000000 
 
  - TimeCreated 

   [ SystemTime]  2011-04-19T20:15:55.000000000Z 
 
   EventRecordID 41303 
 
   Channel System

Comment: What is drive D:?  Is it a optical drive?  An SATA or SAS disk?  USB?  Firewire?  iSCSI?  Is there actually a disk there?

Comment: It's an optical drive, there are rarely disks in it. And powershell will launch fine 99% of the time with no disk in D:

Answer (score 1):

I noticed this happens if there is a disk in the drive at the time it is booted.  If the disk is removed prior to shutting the PC down, this error will occur.  The only fix I have come up with is to eject the disk when shutting down the PC, at the point when it displays the message "Shutting Down".  The next time the PC is booted, there is no disk in the drive to be referenced.  The other way is to manually force eject the cd/dvd tray, if the PC has no power to it, using a paper clip as a pointer in the small hole.

Answer (score 1):

I have been seeing this issue often at my place of work. No fix has gone into place yet, but I have the users right-click the drive and press eject. That will prevent you from getting the error message.

Answer (score 0):

DAEMON Tools caused this issue for me.

```
Open DAEMON Tools Lite
Select Drive
Click Delete Drive
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this issue.  I have a TV monitor connected as a third monitor via HDMI.  If the TV is not on at the time of start-up, I sometimes see this message.  If I turn on the TV and click on "Try Again", it clears the message.